# Missing Ionicons in new Ionic 2 Beta 11 Project

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cross-platform, ionicons

I've set up and started(in the browser) a new Ionic 2 Project with

```
ionic start testProject --v2
cd testProject
ionic serve
```

like it is descibed here: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/getting-started/installation/

Then I played around with the UI and added some Ionicons from the Cheatcheet Version 2 (http://ionicons.com/cheatsheet.html) with

```
<ion-icon name="medical"></ion-icon> => this works...
<ion-icon name="telephone-outline"></ion-icon> => this does not work, is this ios specific??
```

Seems like some of them work, some of them don't. Is this a bug in Ionic 2 Beta 11? How can I find out which Ionicons Version my Ionic Project uses? How can I update my Project to use the latest Version of Ionicons?

Answer (score 1):

As nobody answered I had to look for a solution myself...and no there is no bug in ionic 2 beta 11. I was just looking at the wrong place.

1) To check your Ionicons version look in the global package.json
  => in Ionic 2 beta 11 it's 3.0.0

2) The Ionicons cheachcheet is currently at Version 2.1...(probably because the latest stable Version of Ionic 1 uses this Ionicons Version)=> tadaa version mismatch, that's why some of my icons don't show up

3) Now that I know which Ionicons I have I searched for a Ionicons Version 3 Documentation and found this: 
https://infinitered.github.io/ionicons-version-3-search/

4) The Ios phone icon I was trying to use has been renamed to "ios-call-outlined"...now it works, no need to update anything!:)